# MySQL Matching ANY of collection is subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

i looks for better solution for this query:

```
SELECT * FROM USER 
    WHERE 
    1 IN (SELECT some_id...) OR 
    2 IN (SELECT some_id...) OR 
    3 IN (SELECT some_id...)
```

The subquery can return more than 1 row.

I tried to change it to: `WHERE (1,2,3) IN (SELECT some_id...)` but its throw error:

**Operand should contain 1 column(s)**

I tried some tricks like:

`(1,2,3) = ANY (SELECT some_id...)` - but still same problem.

The result of subquery is only some_ids from second table.

Is there any possible solution for achieve this without multiple OR?

Thanks for help.

Comment: is the query `SELECT some_id...` refer to some other table? If yes, is there a common column you can join them on?

Comment: Yes, there is (SELECT category_id FROM user_category WHERE user.id = user_category.user_id) and returns all available category_id.

Comment: Can you post an example of your whole query?  I feel like there's some other design decisions that could be influencing your issue.

Comment: @SeanGregory original full query is: https://pastebin.com/Zh5NWYUR - the query can contain more than 3 OR - if filter is set for more category ids.

Comment: Please write an example showing sample data for the tables you haves and provide an example of which rows should be selected as a result and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select 1
              from usercategories uc
              where uc.userid = u.userid and
                    uc.categoryid in (1, 2, 3)
             );
```

If you really want to use `in`, you could do:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.userid in (select uc.userid
                   from usercategories uc
                   where uc.categorid in (1, 2, 3)
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it this what you were trying to do?

SELECT * FROM USER 
    WHERE some_id in (1, 2, 3)

Comment: This works - but only for one value in some_id - subquery returns more rows - and ideally i need to get row if ANY OF value is equals. Like (1,2,3) IN ANY (1,2,3,4) - i don't know hot to describe it better. :-/

Comment: This query will return any row that has the column some_id with any of those three values. Can you provide an example in the question if you need something different?

Comment: @Filip . . . Better yet, ask *another* question.  This appears to answer the question that you asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check whether the rows are present or not, then you can use `EXISTS`, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM USER u
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM your_table WHERE some_id IN (1,2,3) AND userid = u.id;
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? (without subqueries)

```
select user.* from user
join user_category on user.id = user_category.id_user
where user_category.category_id in (1,2,3);
```